# Spark Difference in repartition and spark.sql.shuffle.partition

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am running a spark program with `--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=100`

Inside application I have the following

```
Dataset<Row> df_partitioned = df.repartition(df.col("enriched_usr_id"));
df_partitioned = df_partitioned.sortWithinPartitions(df_partitioned.col("transaction_ts"));
df_partitioned.mapPartitions(
    SparkFunctionImpl.mapExecuteUserLogic(), Encoders.bean(Transformed.class));
```

I have around 5 million users and I want to sort data for every user and execute some logic per user.

My question is does this partition the data into 5 million partitions or 100 partitions and how does the execution work per user.

Comment: `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` is used to decide the number of partitions when a shuffle is involved i.e. during joins etc.

Answer (score 0):

`df.repartition(df.col("enriched_usr_id"))` will use enriched_usr_id to partition data into 100 partitions(`spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`), which means multiple users will be in the same partition.